# what is ambigious redirect in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm getting the error "line 8: $mostRecentShare: ambiguous redirect" when there is no kdeconnect* file. It works when a file with that name exists

What am I doing wrong?

The contents of the script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "file changed" >~/systemd.log

mostRecentShare="$(ls ~/| grep kdeconnect* | tail -n 1)"
if [ -z "$mostRecentShare" ]; then
    cd ~/
    xsel -b < $mostRecentShare
fi
rm -f ~/kdeconnect*
```

```
kevin@kevcoder00 ~ $ ./bin/kde-connect-clipboard.sh 
./bin/kde-connect-clipboard.sh: line 8: $mostRecentShare: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: Did you get the logic reversed? Surely you meant `-n` to run the command when there is a file, and not `-z` to run it when there isn't

Comment: @thatotherguy you are of course correct. Thanks. But why do I not get "no such file or directory" which is what xsel -b < "" gives?. what does "ambiguous redirect" actually mean here?

Comment: It's because you don't quote the filename. This causes word splitting, and when this splitting does not result in exactly 1 filename, then Bash considers it ambiguous (though the message makes more sense for 2 filenames than 0)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -z "$mostRecentShare" ]; then
```

You are checking if $mostRecentShare is empty.
I think you want to check if $mostRecentShare is not empty, so use

```
 [ -n "$mostRecentShare" ]
```

Or better use -e to check if file exists (or -f to check that file exists and this is regular file):

```
 [ -f "$mostRecentShare" ]
```